# gcc `python3-config --ldflags` link error on mac

Tags: python, gcc

I'm building blender on my mac . I used pyenv for my python environment. So I change _py_framework of "platform_apple.cmake"  and

set(PLATFORM_LINKFLAGS "${PLATFORM_LINKFLAGS} `python3-config --ldflags`")

but it failed with

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

So I tried in the console with

gcc-4.9 `python3-config --ldflags`

`ld: warning: text-based stub file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation.tbd and library file /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation are out of sync. Falling back to library file for linking.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

So what was wrong  with my gcc?

Comment: Why not just download the program, it's already built: https://www.blender.org/download/

Comment: I want to build the python module , used in my python program